# Activate a conda environment on Visual Studio code Linux

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-code, conda

I am trying to debug some C++ codes, which are linked to the libraries installed in a separate Conda environment. However, 'tasks.json' file is always checking libraries from the base environment, not from the environment that I intend to use. Some error message snippets are as indicated in the screenshot.

Could anyone suggest me how I can activate the environment before the build process for the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

Activate a conda environment and then start Visual Studio in the same shell.

E.g. `code.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

source ~/.bashrc              # init conda
source activate my_env        # activate my_env
exec code "$@" &> ~/code.log  # start VS Code
```